# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in @auth\sequelize-adapter\package.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, package, next-auth

#### Environment

Node: 18.17.1
Yarn: 1.22.19
npm: 9.6.7

#### Describe the issue

The project I am on recently changed from another authentication to `nextAuth.js`. After adding the `Sequelize adapter` by nextAuth.js, I have experienced the Error shown below when using unit tests or customized tools to call Server-side API

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\src\app\node_modules\@auth\sequelize-adapter\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:359:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:639:13)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:567:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:636:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\src\app\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\src\app\src\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\src\app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\src\app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\src\app\src\api\auth.ts:9:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
```

#### Solutions tried

I have tried downgrading/upgrading the packages using `yarn` or `npm`, customizing the export directly in sequelize-adapter package.json, along with trying different `nodejs` versions such as 16,18, and 20 but this problem persists.

#### How to reproduce

execute package.json scripts that call server-side API

#### Expected behavior

Before changing to nextAuth,js and using the Sequelize adapter to manage models, the unit tests and tools function normally when running package.json scripts

#### Actual behavior

I have found that whenever a script is imported and executed a server-side API, the error above will show.
However, the web app and APIs work normally when under development or production.

If you would like to contribute to [Github page](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8597)

Comment: So for now, we have a workaround which is just copying the code we needed from the sequelize-adapter library and pasting it to a customized file, then importing from there